# Copy of entity (rollback purpose) before save?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

As a newbie in my work I got in charge of the project for a colleague who left the company. It was his project so this complicate all work because I am quite alone for everything and also I learn EF as you go along. The project is a client-server app uses EF6, UoW and repository approach.

Let me outline the problem. There is a method on server side in repository

```
MyEntity SaveMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity)
{
    //Do some validation before save - call stored procedure
    //If fails throw exception

    using(var context = new SomeContext())
    {
        //little bit of code for imagination how implementation looks like
        context.my_entity_context_base.Attach(myEntity);
        context.SyncObjectState(myEntity, myEntity.ObjectState);
        context.SaveChanges();

        //...

        if (myEntity.EntityB != null && myEntity.EntityB.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var u in myEntity.EntityB.ToList())
            {
                context.entity_b_context_base.Attach(u);
                context.SyncObjectState(u, u.ObjectState);
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (myEntity.EntityC != null && myEntity.EntityC.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var t in myEntity.EntityC.ToList())
            {
                context.entity_c_context_base.Attach(t);
                context.SyncObjectState(t, t.ObjectState);
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // and so on ..
    }

    //Validation after save - stored procedur is called
    //If fails throws exception
    //If validate_after_save fails there is rollback on DB side.

    base.ExecuteStoredProcedure("validate_after_save", ref parameters, ref errorText);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorText))
    {
        throw new OwnException("Save failed: " + errorText);
    }

    return this.GetMyEtity(myEntity.id);
}
```

When no exception is threw everything is fine but when validation after save throws ex the client side doesn't get actual entity. This is really problem in some scenarios as I found out previously. For exmple I want save entity. Validation after save throws ex (so client doesn't receive the entity). So I'll change something and save it again. Because previous validation after save throws an exception the client has still the state "Added" so it throws primary key violation ex.

So I got the task to create same mechanism wich makes rollback in EF. When the exception is threw they want original data. As you can see in the code above there is nothing like that now. Of course, I have transaction on my mind but how is it possible to implement it to current implementation you can see above?

My idea is get the current entity from DB. In the case of exception I call SaveMyEntity with data I got before save. But few problems:

1. I am not sure where to store the reference of original data (client
   or server)?
2. I'll have to change the state of original entity.
3. This smells of corruption of relations

Can I have some advice from you?

Thanks a lot!

---

EDIT:

I just found out existence of TransactionScope. So I tried do something like this

```
void SaveMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity)
{
    //...

    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
            new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
    {
        using(var context = new SomeContext())
        {
            //...

            if (myEntity.EntityB != null && myEntity.EntityB.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var u in myEntity.EntityB.ToList())
                {
                    context.entity_b_context_base.Attach(u);
                    context.SyncObjectState(u, u.ObjectState);
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (myEntity.EntityC != null && myEntity.EntityC.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var t in myEntity.EntityC.ToList())
                {
                    context.entity_c_context_base.Attach(t);
                    context.SyncObjectState(t, t.ObjectState);
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // and so on ..
        }

        base.ExecuteStoredProcedure("validate_after_save", ref parameters, ref errorText);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorText))
        {
            //Rollback
            scope.Dispose();
            throw new OwnException("Save failed: " + errorText);
        }
        else
        {
            //Commit
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

And it actually works nice. But I am not sure if it is right solution.

Comment: Why not validate entity before saving?

Comment: Why is the validation done in a stored procedure that is called after the (possibly invalid data) was committed to the DB? And how does it roll back data?

Comment: Validation is done in the stored procedure because of business logic purpose. This is really huge application which has 80% of business logic in stored procedures (also because of historical reason). There are tons of tables in DB which is needed to check, update or insert to. It is not so simply. Code above is just a part of one module of approx. 80.

Comment: Adil Mammadov there is validation before save but is also stored procedure. I know that this is abolutly bad concept but ...  Is really hard to make some big changes. I try find simple and effective solution if there some exists.

Comment: I think you will fighting a lot with EF state management if you need to be able to provide original data after a failed update call.  Transactions are the way to go if you don't want anything to be change during the whole trying to save process...